# Secondary DNS is not responding to dig

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

We are new to DNS. we are trying to configure a secondary DNS server using Bind & CentOS for an existing primary server (Eg:142.250.192.110).

Our secondary server configuration is as follows:

```
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; any; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; any; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any; };

    
zone "example.com" IN {
        type slave;
        masters {  142.250.192.110; };
        file "slaves/example.forward";
};
zone "192.250.142.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        masters {  142.250.192.110; };
        file "slaves/example.reverse";
};
```

When we executed `dig @127.0.0.1 host1.example.com` we are getting a proper reply.
When we executed with local IP (Secondary Server), `dig @192.168.1.10 host1.example.com` we are getting a proper reply.

But when we execute command with public IP / hostname of a secondary server, Eg: `dig @dns2.example.com host1.example.com` we are getting errors like `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Please suggest some help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for your valuable time and help.

**Some information and troubleshoot details (IP & hostname is not original):**

Primary DNS: 142.250.192.110 (dns1.example.com)

Secondary DNS: 192.168.1.10 (local IP), 142.250.192.220 (dns2.example.com)

```
nslookup dns2.example.com

Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dns2.example.com
Address: 142.250.192.220
```

`dig @127.0.0.1 host1.example.com` - Success

`dig @192.168.1.10 host1.example.com` - Success

`dig @142.250.192.220 host1.example.com` - Failed.

`dig @dns2.example.com host1.example.com` - Failed.

**tcpdump** shows packet transfer, with `dig @127.0.0.1` and `dig @192.168.1.10`.
But shows **NO packet transfer**, with `dig @142.250.192.220` and `dig @dns2.example.com`.

To check, whether the firewall is blocking port 53, we tested the port with tcpdump and tcpdump shows packet transfer when did `telnet 142.250.192.220 53`

**Note:** We have a firewall that does NAT local IP with Public IP. We are waiting for the reply from the network team, whether Firewall is blocking this dig request.

Comment: Is 192.168.1.10 the private IP of the secondary DNS server?

Comment: Yes. it is the private IP of secondary DNS.

Comment: That means `dns2.example.com` does not resolve to your correct IP but something else. The first step for `dig` when using `@` is to resolve that name to be able to contact it to then send a DNS query to it.

Comment: Updated question with IP details and troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always check the logs on both servers.
Verify that the slave has been able to fetch the zone.
One step is to do the transfer manually using `dig @192.168.1.10 axfr example.com` from the slave, where `@192.168.1.10` is the master in the slave config.

`allow-transfer { };` might be needed on master to allow the slave to fetch the zone.
Again, all this is in the logs.

Always check local access first.
Check with netstat -anp if the server is listening properly, and again check the logs. and as a last resort, try tcpdump to see which packets go where and if there is any reply.

Comment: dig @PrimaryDNS_IP axfr example. com is a success. Output is
........
;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: PRIMARY_IP.53#53(PRIMARY_IP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jul 27 23:48:17 IST 2021
;; XFR size: 94 records (messages 1, bytes 2877)

It looks like secondary can talk to primary.

Comment: Updated question with IP details and troubleshooting steps.

Comment: note that DNS uses both UDP and TCP on port 53, use "netstat -anp | grep 53" to check both, verify if it listens on specific ips, or the "any" 0.0.0.0 address, (which it should with your config, but don't harm to verify)

With the basics covered, I'd say you have a routing/firewall issue.